# Include mpi to make file

Tags: makefile, mpi

I am trying to include MPI compiler to my makefile. The makefile is already prepared such that I only need to include the address of the MPI compiler in a a separate env file. However doing so does not work. I can get the cpp file to run manually by typing:

```
mpicxx Demo_00.cpp -o aprogram
./aprogram
```

I test where the mpi compiler is located using:

```
which mpicxx
/usr/bin/mpicxx
```

In the env file the corresponding line is:

```
MPICXX=/usr/bin/mpicxx
```

However, when I try to 'make' he cpp file I get the following error:

```
make Demo_00
g++     Demo_00.cpp   -o Demo_00
Demo_00.cpp:2:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Demo_00] Error 1
```

The cpp file is in the same folder as the env file and the makefile.

I am not quite sure how to identify the error.

Thank you for your help,
Tartaglia

Comment: Why do you need an env file? Would running mpicxx instead of g++ do the right thing? You don't show us any of the involved files.

Comment: I am using a Modeling Suite that uses makefile, so I have to go with the flow here.

Comment: It's not clear from your question and comments that you know that `mpicxx` is generally not a compiler in its own right, but a wrapper for another compiler.  It may be that on your installation the wrapped compiler is `g++`, which would explain why you are getting error messages from it.

Comment: I was not aware of this, thank you for pointing out the difference. But if the wrapped compiler is actually g++, why am I getting this error message. I am basically trying to follow instructions from this tutorial (last section at the very end):

http://repast.sourceforge.net/hpc_tutorial/RepastHPC_Demo_00_Step_01.html

It shows how to compile using mpicxx, and the recommends automating this by adding the path to mpicxx in the env file mentioned above.

Comment: Show us an example Makefile. Otherwise it's a shot in the dark trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in your log file:

```
g++     Demo_00.cpp   -o Demo_00
```

says that you are using g++ compiler instead of mpixx.

Usually in makefiles compiler definition is at the beginnig of the file and looks like this:

```
CC=g++
```

just change it to mpixx

```
CC=mpixx
```

Comment: @ Tomasz Bekas and MadScientiest: Thank you so much for your quick responses.

I could actually not find anything in the makefile that says CC=g++, and I am not sure where I can change the variable CXX.

Is it possible that I am actually not using the makefile in this folder but another one? How do I control which makefile is considered when typing make 'filename'?

Comment: There are built-in defaults; this is probably not defined in your Makefile at all. Just try `make CXX=mpicxx` or matbe the same for `CC`. If it works, add it to the beginning of your Makefile.

Comment: So adding CXX=mpicxx or CC=mpixx did not change anything, I still get the message that g++ is used.

Comment: So instead of using make Demo_00, I now typed make -f makefile Demo_00 (the name of my makefile is 'makefile'), to make sure that this file is used, and I am still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the name of the C++ compiler, you have to change the variable `CXX`.  That's the default variable make uses when it wants to compile C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses, I took a closer look into the makefile I thought I was using and it turns out, as you have already suggested, I was not using it at all. The makefile was only able to execute one specific cpp file with one specific name. So whenever I typed in make *.cpp I was using the standard make as you already pointed out.

Thanks again for your help.